# Highlight Duplicates Not Next To Each Other Using Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

We have a list of parts in Excel in a certain order. For reasons I won't get into, we need to highlight when there are duplicates that aren't next to each other. Currently, I'm using this formula in a conditional format to do the job.

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$82,$A2)>1,$A1<>$A2,$A2<>$A3)
```

This mostly works well except in cases where there are pairs of duplicates like in the example below, we would want FO-1694 to be highlighted, because they aren't all next to each other. But we would not want NIS0257 to be highlighted because they are.

[image: Current]

Ideally, this is what we want to see...

[image: Expected]

Any ideas on this could be achieved using conditional formatting?

Comment: If it is possible, it needs to be done with conditional formatting and a formula. Each cell needs to be checked against the rest of the column for dupes, but ignore x-1 and x+1 where x is the current row. I don't know how to exclude x-1 and x+1. Good luck!

Comment: So if all instances of a number aren't in sequential cells, they need to be highlighted? Why not use a macro?

Comment: @Raystafarian, there are already so many VBA macros that execute on cell change that the worksheet is slow to work with sometimes. And that's after turning off `ScreenUpdating`. `Calculation`, and `EnableEvents`. So, I really want to avoid adding anymore to it than I have to.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below was posted on StackOverflow by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) to the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098014/highlight-duplicates-not-next-to-each-other-using-conditional-formatting) (posted there because there was no working answer here):

> Use this formula:
>
> ```
> =NOT(AND(A2=OFFSET(A2,COUNTIF($A2:$A$82,A2)-1,0),A2=OFFSET(A2,-(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1),0)))
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> If changing the range then make sure to pay attention to what is
> marked as absolute and relative.

Source answer [Highlight Duplicates Not Next To Each Other Using Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098014/highlight-duplicates-not-next-to-each-other-using-conditional-formatting/35098161#35098161) by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Comment: I feel that I did as the rules said to. Am I missing something? I'm sorry, I don't mean to cause any trouble. I tried to make it very clear that I had no part in creating the answer.

Comment: Let me fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! Sorry, I'm new at referencing others' answer. I'll note the format for in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Rule #1:

> Rule: =$A1=$A2
>
> Applies to: =$A$1:$A$15
>
> Formatting: None (No Fill, etc)

Rule #2:

> Rule: =$A1=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-1,0)
>
> Applies to: =$A$1:$A$15
>
> Formatting: None (No Fill, etc)

Rule #3:

> Just normal "Duplicate Values"
>
> Formatting: What ever you like (Highlight in Red)

See below:

[image]